# Simulating conditional distribution in R

Tags: r, database, conditional-statements, simulation, distribution

I have a question about simulating conditional distribution.

Suppose

```
X ~ N(0,1)

Y ~ N(rX, 1-r^2)
```

I want to simulate `Y` distribution which is conditioning on `X`.

The `r` in here is the correlation, and it can be changed for purpose.

The `X` distribution code would be as follows;

```
sd.x <- 1

mean.x <- 0

z2 <- rnorm(1000)

x <- sd.x*z2 + mean.x
```

But, I have no idea about simulating `Y` distribution.

I'll be appreciate with help.

Comment: sampling from joint distribution? check out this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180991/how-to-generate-random-samples-from-joint-normal-distribution-with-r

Comment: You mean bivariate distribution? Is it the same process in bivariate normal distribution?

Comment: seems like you are simulating bivariate normal distribution

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are in the case of a linear regression ...
You can write Y = rX + epsilon, where epsilon folows N(0,(1-r)^2).
You can chek that Y has the properties you are looking for ..

So, in r, to complete your code, somthing like this should be enough :

```
r <- 0.8
y <- r*x + rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1-r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use the `mvrnorm` function from the `MASS` package, like this:

```
sample <- mvrnorm(1000, mu=c(0,0), matrix(c(1, r, r, 1-r^2), 2, 2))
```

Or, as a more general approach simulate `X` then simulate `Y` for each value of `X`

```
sample <- data.frame(X = rnorm(1000))

sample$Y <- sapply(sample$X, function(x){
  rnorm(1, r*x, 1-r ^2)
})
```